# Cython: Memory ownership issue between Python/C++ when storing pointers

Tags: python, cython

I'm having a memory ownership issue between Python/C++ code using Cython. I'm not sure what is the best way to address this. So I appreciate any help.

My strategy is as follows:

1. Create a C++ NetInfo data structure with get/set members.
2. Populate this data structure in Python (the data is parsed from files and SqLiteDB lookup is done). Thus, I need to cythonize NetInfo.
3. Pass the NetInfo objects into C++ 'processing' routines to operate on them. These will also be cythonized.

For a NetInfo object, I need to store pointers to other NetInfo objects to indicate interaction between two objects.

My (relevant) C++ code is as follows:

```
struct NetInfoData;
class NetInfo {
public:
    NetInfo();
    NetInfo(NetInfo const& rhs);
    virtual ~NetInfo();
    ...
    std::vector<NetInfo*> getBridgedNets() const;
    void addBridgedNet(NetInfo const* ni);  
protected:
      NetInfoData* data_;
};
struct NetInfoData
{
     std::string name;
     ...
     std::vector<NetInfo*>  bridged_nets; <-- NOTE: Storing pointers.
};
NetInfo::NetInfo()
    : data_(0)
{
    std::cout << "Constructor " << this << std::endl;
    data_ = new NetInfoData();
}
NetInfo::~NetInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor " << this << std::endl;
    delete data_;
}
NetInfo::NetInfo(NetInfo const& rhs)
    : data_(0)
{
    std::cout << "Copy constructor " << this << std::endl;
    data_ = new NetInfoData();
    data_->name = rhs.data_->name;
    ...
    data_->bridged_nets = rhs.data_->bridged_nets;
}
std::vector<NetInfo*>
NetInfo::getBridgedNets() const
{
    return data_->bridged_nets;
}

void
NetInfo::addBridgedNet(NetInfo* n)
{
    data_->bridged_nets.push_back(n);
}
```

My (relevant) Cython code is as follows. It compiles/works OK.

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from 'NetInfo.h':
    cdef cppclass NetInfo:
        NetInfo() except +
        NetInfo(NetInfo&) except +
        ...
        vector[NetInfo*] getBridgedNets()
        void             addBridgedNet(NetInfo*)

cdef class PyNetInfo:
    cdef NetInfo* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, PyNetInfo ni=None):
        if ni is not None:
            self.thisptr = new NetInfo(deref(ni.thisptr))
        else:
            self.thisptr = new NetInfo()
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    ...
    def get_bridged_nets(self):
        cdef PyNetInfo r
        cdef NetInfo* n
        cdef vector[NetInfo*] nets = self.thisptr.getBridgedNets()

        result = []
        for n in nets:
            r = PyNetInfo.__new__(PyNetInfo)
            r.thisptr = n
            result.append(r)
        return result

    def add_bridged_net(self, PyNetInfo ni):
        self.thisptr.addBridgedNet(ni.thisptr)
```

Now my Python pseudo-code is as follows:

```
import PyNetInfo as NetInfo

a = NetInfo()               # Create a
Update data members of a    # Populate a

tmp = NetInfo(a)     # Call copy constructor of a
for n in xrange(5):  # a interacts with five other NetInfo objects so create and call them to a via add_bridged_net() 
   x = NetInfo(tmp)  # Call copy constructor to make copy of tmp (not a!!)
   Update data members of x

   a.add_bridged_net(x)   # Store pointer to x in a (a is updated!)
```

The offending piece of code is **x = NetInfo(tmp)**. On the **2nd iteration**, the old memory assigned to x will be released as x is now pointing to a a new object. This will cause a to contain an invalid pointer now.

Sample run :

```
create a
Constructor 0x101ecd0

create tmp
Copy constructor 0xd71d30

create bridge x
Copy constructor 0xd71bb0
add bridged net:  

create bridge x
Copy constructor 0xc9f740
Destructor 0xd71bb0   <--- Destructor on old x is called due to reassignment which causes a to contain an invalid pointer (hence, eventually segfault)
add bridged net:
```

I'm not totally sure how to manage the memory to fix this. Can anyone help?

I'm thinking maybe using shared pointers? So in my C++ code, I say

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<NetInfo> NetInfoShPtr;
```

Then,

```
std::vector<NetInfo*> bridged_nets -> std::vector<NetInfoShPtr> bridged_nets;
```

But then I'm not sure what to do on the cython side of things. Will this work or there is some other (easier?) way? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
a.add_bridged_net(x)
```

a reference to `x` is not stored, only a pointer to a `NetInfo` instance is added to the vector. Since python object `x` is not referenced, `x` will be deallocated and consequently the corresponding pointer to C++ `NetInfo` instance i.e. there will be a pointer in the vector that points to a deallocated object.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue using shared pointers (let it do all the dirty work of managing). The only hassle is now need to use a lot of deref(self.thisptr) everywhere in Cython to call the C++ get/set methods :).

C++ change:

```
class NetInfo
typedef std::shared_ptr<NetInfo> NetInfoShPtr;

class NetInfo {
public:
    NetInfo();
    NetInfo(NetInfo const& rhs);
    virtual ~NetInfo();
    ...
    std::vector<NetInfoShPtr> getBridgedNets() const;
    void addBridgedNet(NetInfoShPtr const& ni);  
protected:
      NetInfoData* data_;
};
```

Cython change:

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr

cdef extern from 'NetInfo.h':
    ctypedef shared_ptr[NetInfo] NetInfoShPtr

    cdef cppclass NetInfo:
        NetInfo() except +
        NetInfo(NetInfo&) except +
        ...
        vector[NetInfoShPtr] getBridgedNets()
        void                 addBridgedNet(NetInfoShPtr&)

cdef class PyNetInfo:
    cdef NetInfoShPtr thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, PyNetInfo ni=None):
        if ni is not None:
            self.thisptr = NetInfoShPtr(new NetInfo(deref(ni.thisptr)))
        else:
            self.thisptr = new NetInfoShPtr(new NetInfo())
    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.thisptr.reset()   # no del, reset the shared pointer
    ...
    def get_bridged_nets(self):
        cdef PyNetInfo r
        cdef NetInfoShPtr n
        cdef vector[NetInfoShPtr] nets = deref(self.thisptr).getBridgedNets()   # Must derefence

        result = []
        for n in nets:
            r = PyNetInfo.__new__(PyNetInfo)
            r.thisptr = n
            result.append(r)
        return result

    def add_bridged_net(self, PyNetInfo ni):
        deref(self.thisptr).addBridgedNet(ni.thisptr)  # Must dereference
```